# Package name lookup rules in scala

Tags: scala

I came out to scala programmin from Java so it's not clear to me how we should use relative imports in Scala and what is the exact name lookup rules? Suppose I have the following:

```
pack.age
   |
   |----MyClass.scala

com.age
   |
   |---AnotherClass.scala
```

I need to import `MyClass.scala` into `AnotherClass.scala`. Since Scala supports only relative imports I wrote the following:

```
import _root_.pack.age.MyClass
```

and it worked fine. But when I tried to delete `_root_` from there, there was no compile time error either.

```
import pack.age.MyClass
```

works fine as well.

So, what is the package name lookup rules in Scala?

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is an order of operations here. If you had package.age.MyClass within com.age (ie. com.age.package.age.MyClass), as well as package.age.MyClass, the former would be picked up. If you wanted the latter, you would need to use the *root* syntax.

As there is only one place this class can be picked up from (in *root*), that is the package picked up.

Answer (score 3):

All imports are relative, so sometimes collisions can appear. For example, if you have `package com.org.project.scala` then next `import scala._` looks up for system package too. `_root_` is implicit top package that can be utilised for simulation of absolute path.